# Unable to access identity settings. When using git-gateway backend make sure to enable Identity service and Git Gateway - Netlify

Tags: netlify

When using **Netlify** the authentication fails and I got the message:

```
Unable to access identity settings. 
When using git-gateway backend make sure to enable Identity service and Git Gateway.
```

Answer (score 6):

You must reconnect the repo, and reactivate the git gateway, to it back to work.

1. Go to **Settings > Build & deploy > Continuous Deployment > Build settings** to re-link the repository.
2. Go to **Settings > Identity > Services > Git Gateway** to add a new API access token following the instructions in the section above.

Wait it rebuild and it should work properly.

It may happen after change repository permissions or netlify password, change ownership on your repository, or convert a repository from public to private.